# Unified Kernel Image Buildroot

Tags: linux-kernel, uefi, buildroot

Is it possible to create Unified Kernel Image using Buildroot?
I want to pack rootfs.cpio.xz and Kernel Image (EFI Stub) into a single file that can be loaded from EFI Shell.

Answer (score 0):

**Enable EFI stub support**

Run `make linux-menuconfig` and edit:

```
Processor type and features  --->

    [*] EFI runtime service support 
    [*]   EFI stub support
    [?]     EFI mixed-mode support
```

EFI mixed-mode support is enabled by default in the kernel settings.
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/EFI_Stub